# I get message 'Missing type map configuration or unsupported mapping.'

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, automapper

I have two class

```
    public class AddressRequestModel
    {
        public Guid? UserKey { get; set; }
        public string AddressLine1 { get; set; }
        public string AddressLine2 { get; set; }
        public int ZipCode { get; set; }
        public string Location { get; set; }
        public bool IsActive { get; set; }
    }
    public class AddressRequestModelList
    {
        public List<AddressRequestModel> AddressRequestModel { get; set; }
    }
```

one entity

```
    public class Address
    {
        [Key]
        public Guid AddressKey { get; set; }
        public string AddressLine1{ get; set; }
        public string AddressLine2 { get; set; }
        public int ZipCode { get; set; }
        public string Location { get; set; }

        
        public Guid UserKey { get; set; }
   
        public bool IsActive { get; set; }
    }
```

and one profile mapper

```
 public class Profiler :Profile
    { 
        public Profiler()
        {
           CreateMap<List<AddressRequestModelList>, List<Address>>();
        }

    }
```

when mapping this controller I get message  'Missing type map configuration or unsupported mapping.'

```
public IEnumerable<AddressDto> CreateAddress(AddressRequestModelList addressRequestModel)
        {
                var requestModel = _mapper.Map<List<Address>>(addressRequestModel);
                ...
        }
```

I need help.

Comment: Post the full exception text, not just the message. You can get it easily with `Exception.ToString()` or by clicking on `Copy Details` in the exception popup while debugging. The full text probably explains which types couldn't be mapped

Answer (score 0):

It's unusual to specify mappings between collection types; usually you would map the item types:

```
public class Profiler : Profile
{ 
    public Profiler()
    {
       CreateMap<AddressRequestModel, Address>();
    }
}
```

AutoMapper is able to perform a collection mapping based on this:

```
public IEnumerable<AddressDto> CreateAddress(AddressRequestModelList addressRequestModel)
{
    var requestModel = _mapper.Map<List<Address>>(addressRequestModel.AddressRequestModel);
    //...
}
```

This is more flexible than using `List<T>` because other collection types can be used as necessary: https://docs.automapper.org/en/stable/Lists-and-arrays.html

---

If you must specify a mapping to a `List<T>` you could do something like this:

```
public class Profiler : Profile
{ 
    public Profiler()
    {
       CreateMap<AddressRequestModel, Address>();

       CreateMap<AddressRequestModelList, List<Address>>()
           .ConstructUsing(
               (src, context) => context.Mapper.Map<List<Address>>(src.AddressRequestModel));
    }
}

public IEnumerable<AddressDto> CreateAddress(AddressRequestModelList addressRequestModel)
{
    var requestModel = _mapper.Map<List<Address>>(addressRequestModel);
    //...
}
```